# Is Aegean Air's cancellation penalty for Flex/ComfortFlex applied per booking, per leg, per passenger, or somehow else?

Tags: airlines, cancellations, refunds, fare-class, aegean-airlines

Consider one-way tickets from Paris to Larnaka with Aegean Air on December 1, 2022 for two adults. The website shows a price per adult per ticket (not per leg); if I choose a fare, the doubled number is added to my basket. Here I chose the "Flex" fare for 193.20 EUR and my basket now contains 386.40 EUR worth of flights.

[image]

Their "Fare Comparison" button bring up the following table which says "Cancellation fee: 50 EUR" for both Flex and ComfortFlex classes:

[image]

However, it's not clear what the total refund would be if I purchase these tickets and return them in a month. I pay 386.40 EUR now, I get everything back less the cancellation fee. If it's per booking, I get back 336.40 EUR, if it's per adult per ticket, I get back 286.40 EUR, and if it's per adult per leg I get back 186.40 EUR only. Quite a difference.

Aegean Air's ["Fares & Classes" page](https://en.aegeanair.com/plan/booking-info/fares-classes/economy-class/) do not sched much light: see "Flex fare rules", "International flights", "Ticket refund in case of cancellation", and it says "Allowed, non-refundable fare amount: Short International Flights [1] & [2]: 50 EUR".

What is the total cancellation fee for such a booking?

I have the exact same question for Austrian Airlines who say "Refundable, except 70 EUR" during booking and nowhere else, but let's keep it one at a time.

Comment: For example, some [TripAdvisor discussions about Emirates](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k8166960-Emirates_cancellation_fees_per_booking_or_per_passenger-Air_Travel.html) from 7 years ago mentions that "Cancellation fees are usually for each ticket. With 4 people , you have 4 tickets. Each ticket has a cancellation fee.", which results in 286.40 EUR refund in my case.

Answer (score 4):

https://en.aegeanair.com/plan/fare-rules/ lists a bewildering number of cases based in fare class and route. Most international ones read something like this.

> II. Flex Fare (Y, B, M, H, Q, V, L, K, S, T, U, P Class): The fare and taxes are refunded. There is a cancellation penalty of €50 per direction, paid by the passenger to the company.  In case of no-show refund is not permitted.

I would interpret this as 50 Euro per direction per ticket, so the total cancellation fee would be 200 Euro or about half of the ticket price.

It's also not clear to me whether this would be an actual cash refund or just travel credit. You may have to call the airline and ask.

Comment: I think "per direction per ticket" yields 2 fees for a one-way ticket? I'll update the question to say it's one-way

Comment: At this point it may be best to call the airlines. There are multiple ways to interpret the wording in the terms and conditions.